# Windows 8 Licensing on new PCs - can I wipe the HDD?

Tags: windows-8, bloatware

I read that new Windows 8 PCs don't have the COD with the serial on the bottom, and I wonder if this is gonna causing problems on reinstallation.

Usually when I have a new PC, this is what I do:

1. Wipe the HDD to get rid of crazy partition layouts and crapware (on Win8 [looks that's going crazier](http://www.itworld.com/consumerization-it/319281/heres-all-crapware-comes-new-windows-8-pcs) than ever!)
2. Reinstall Windows

But, it looks like the OS installation on the HDD is tied to the machine with a code on the BIOS - that means if I wipe, I cant install it anymore legitemately - is that true?

Comment: Computers that come with Windows 8 have recovery sectors just like computers that come with Windows 7 do.  You have an option when using the recovery sector NOT to install the additioanl software.

Comment: that might be true for one or two OEMs, but certainly not all of them. Some PCs dont even come with a recovery partition.

Comment: @TaylorGibb - ALL OEMS are required to either give you the option to create a recovery disk or have the recovery parition on the hdd. This requirement is set by Microsoft.

Comment: I wonder if the recovery partition has the crapware preinstalled or not

Comment: @Ramhound I never said that they don't give you any option at all, what I actually meant was that they could also include an install disc if they don't want to include a partition.

Comment: Don't have access to a new Win8 machine to test, but wonder whether the new **Reset** feature (which removes all personal data, **apps**, and settings from the PC, and reinstalls Windows) will get rid of the crapware as well?

Comment: Crapware will be reinstalled :-/ Warning: The apps that came with your PC or you installed from Windows Store will be reinstalled http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Comment: The "only" way to get rid of crapware and get a clean system is to wipe the hdd and install Windows from a DVD - the point of the question is that the DVD version will read the serial from the BIOS or not.

Comment: @Magnetic_dud i did answer your question, i dont know why you accepted the other one, but anyway....

Comment: Both were good. But I upvoted your answer, it was at -1 (i don't know why, it's right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this Blog post you can use a clean ISO and the setup detect your OEM key:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2012/11/16/windows-8-bios-keys-embedded-goodness.aspx

> If you look at the bottom of my machine, you’ll notice there is no Windows 8 Certificate of Authenticity (COA).  There is an official Windows 8 logo sticker, but no product key.
>
> The good news is that you no longer have to worry about it fading or getting scratched.  The 5x5 key is embedded in the BIOS.  Therefore all I had to do in order to install a fresh clean copy of Windows 8 was attach an external DVD drive, boot from the retail DVD, and run setup. As soon as I connected to the internet, the machine activated.  It never asked me for a key.  No fuss!!!

Comment: While this answer is a great answer its missing important information. This solution requires you have a copy of Windows 8 ( x64/x86 ) on some media in order to do this. At this time the the only tool I am aware that can download the iso is the upgrade assistance which only offers the download after you purchase Windows 8. Of course the application that downloads the ISO isn't behind a pay wall. I might post an answer to this "problem" if I get around to it.  This note is based on the fact the author had trouble creating the recovery media for his Windows 8 OEM system.

Comment: download a fresh ISO from the internet and compare the hashes to make sure you have an untouched ISO. MSFT posts the hashes on Technet/MSDN

Comment: The iso that the Upgrade Assistance Tool downloads does not match the hashes on Technet/MSDN.  This answer is still incomplete, based on the dismisal attitude you have about my feedback, makes me wish I waited to vote on it.

Comment: yes, the tool downloads an encrypted Image (ESD) file. Ask a friend who has access to the Win8 ISO from Technet/MSDN or google for the ISO with the name "en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso" with the SHA1 hash of "1CE53AD5F60419CF04A715CF3233F247E48BEEC4"

Comment: yes this answer is certainly legit, advising you to download an ISO from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can still install it. The key is tied to your BIOS, when you do a clean installation the installation wizard detects that you have an OEM key in your BIOS.

Once Windows has finished installing your PC will connect to the internet and activate.