# Get my OEMs key

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation, oem

I had Win8 installed on my samsung laptop. But I removed it and the recovery partition too. In fact I nuked my drive. Is there anyway I can get my key back.

Comment: What is your definition of "nuked"?  This is impossible to answer without details of exactly what you did.

Comment: You need to use software that can read the key in the embedded firmware.  Can you remove the vulgarity please? [You also don't need the key, it will automatically, be detected.](http://superuser.com/questions/538302/reinstall-windows-8-on-a-windows-8-based-system-with-embedded-key)

Comment: @fixer1234 nuking is a term used when you completely erase all data from hard drive either by rewriting the entire drive with 0s or random bits or chars

Answer (score 0):

Your key is actually stored in the BIOS. But don't go looking for it in there.

Since microsoft decided to remove the stickers at the bottom of your laptop,
[image: Windows 7 Sticker]

Your only choice will be to use a software to retrieve the missing key.

Download [this software](http://www.nextofwindows.com/download/WpKey.zip) and unzip the software, after opening `pkeyui.exe` try searching for it with the MSDM option checked,

[image: Product Key Viewer]

and that will give you your OEM product key.

Comment: Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 devices do not have COA on them.  All Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 devices have an embedded firmware which contains the key.  He has a Windows 8 device, he will not have a sticker, with the key on it.  He also don't have Windows installed, so running a windows program, really isn't an option.