# Can I format my computer to Windows 10 without using the product key?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Lenovo laptop that had Windows 8 preinstalled on it, and I upgraded it to Windows 10 while it was free for Windows 7/8 users.  I would like to format the laptop to Windows 10 so I can sell it, but I can't find a way to reinstall Windows 10 without any sort of product key.  Is it possible to format my laptop to Windows 10 without a product key?

This is not related to the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/946348) this is marked a duplicate of because that question is about making a clean install of Windows 10 using the free upgrade.  I am asking if, after the free upgrade, if I can clear all the files/programs/settings/etc..

Comment: Just use your Windows 8.1 key

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 8 came preinstalled on it, so it did not give me a Windows product key

Comment: You still have one, there are existing questions on how you determine what it is, but Windows 10 also will automatically detect and accept your a windows 8.1 key

Comment: @Ramhound I looked up how to find my product key, but all I got is that on Windows 10, these programs will return generic keys because Windows 10 changed how the keys work.

Comment: Your Windows 8.1 key is embedded in firmware, there are existing questions, that explain how to determine what that key is, but that is not a required step because once again I will repeat the installer will AUTOMATICALLY detect what the Windows 8.1 key is and accept it

Comment: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/538302/reinstall-windows-8-on-a-windows-8-based-system-with-embedded-key/633683#633683) is a tool that will get your Windows 8.1 key, but again, not a required step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install the free Windows 7/8 -> 10 upgrade on a new empty drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/946348/can-i-install-the-free-windows-7-8-10-upgrade-on-a-new-empty-drive)

Comment: " Is it possible to format my laptop to Windows 10 without a product key?", it is a dupe according to your original question. Yes its possible and there are several ways to approach how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Reset your Windows 10 installation. Check out this [link - Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options) and expand the "Reset Your PC" link to see where to find the option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. During Windows 10 Setup, select the “I don’t have a product key” option and continue as usual. After it is completely installed, **Windows 10 will automatically restore a previous activation on the same machine.** An Internet connection is required.